# Products of primes up to the $n$th prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology, primorial

The first prime is $2$. The second prime is $3$. $3\cdot 2 = 6$. The product of the first three primes is $30$. The product of all the primes up to the fourth prime is $210$.

My question is this: Is this sequence described in words as the products of all primes up to the $n$th prime?

The first few members of this sequence are $2$, $6$, $30$, $210$, $2310$, $30030$, $510510\dots$

Comment: The symbol $\#$ is typically used like so: $k\#$ is the multiplication of all primes less than or equal to $k$.

Comment: Terminology can differ, but Mathworld, OEIS, and Wikipedia all seem consistent that the primorial $p_n\#$ is what you are describing: the product of the first $n$ primes (OEIS A002110).  $n\#$ is the product of all primes less than or equal to $n$ (OEIS A034386).  See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html) for example.

Comment: The OEIS explicit [reference](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C6%2C30%2C210%2C2310%2C30030%2C510510&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: The sequence of primorials is part of the foundation of the proof of the fact that the maximum distance from any given number $n$ to the next prime is less than twice the square root of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Described in words, this sequence is called the [Primorials](https://oeis.org/A002110) (prime + factorial) and is often written as
$$\text{prime}(n)\#,$$
but note that there isn't anything wrong with your terminology: "products of all primes up to the $n$th prime."